# How to run particular file with Playwright?

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I have multiple test files in a specific folder with extension spec.ts. How I can run a particular file with Playwright?

Currently for configuration is set as the test folder and will run all files (tests) from it:

```
testDir: './smokeTests',
```

I assume that there is some option in the config file, but I'm not sure which one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use testMatch in config:

```
testMatch:['sampleTest.spec.ts']
```

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-testconfig#test-config-test-match

Comment: Also, if you want to run it outside of your config and as part of your terminal command line you can use `npx playwright test sampleTest.spec.ts`